# What is the purpose of SSH settings while upgrading TFS to AzureDevops 2019 in the Server Configuration Wizard?

Tags: azure-devops

I am working on an Azure Devops upgrade on premises. We are currently on TFS2018.Update2 and are planning on upgrading to Azure Devops 2019. After the installation I am updating configuration via the server configuration wizard. Under Application Tier -> SSH Settings, there is a checkbox to enable SSH Service/Port# 22.

I'm not able to understand what is the purpose of that setting. I'm still looking around to see if there is good documentation around that. Anyone has any recommended reading in this regard?
[image]

Comment: I think these two documents([blog](https://www.wintellect.com/vsts-ssh/), [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=current-page)) can make you some help. The ssh service is mostly used with git repos.

Comment: For example: If you enable that, when you try to clone repos from tfs, you have both http and ssh ways. If you disable that, when you click the clone in `Code`, you can only see http option there.

Answer (score 1):

If you check that, then your collection will have the feature of SSH authentication.
That option is mostly used with git repos.

For Azure Devops Server 2019, open your project in web portal, click the Code button and you can see:

[image]

Normally we can click the `Clone` button to clone the files to local machine. If we enable the SSH service, we can see two options:

[image]

If you don't check that, only http is available for your collection when clone repos:

[image]

**In addition:** You can change this setting any time if needed even after the installation or upgrade. See:

[image]